# Zend_Gdata_Calendar : Get past events from google calendar

Tags: php

I am using the below code to fetch events from google calendar. But I am not able to fetch past events,

```
$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
$query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser('default');
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('composite');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('ascending');
$query->setFutureevents('true');
$query->setParam('singleevents','true');
$eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
```

Please help me find all events.

**Note: It's not a Zend Framework project, Just using Zend libraries in another project**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been so many days after posted my question, I didn't get even a comment. I've spent so many time for these and got a solution. I figured it as very close to my question.

```
$query->setStartMin('2006-12-01');
$query->setStartMax('2014-12-16');
```

This will fetch events from that starting time to max time.

```
 $query->setStartMin('2006-12-01');
```

Above will work as fetching events from staring time to future ones, no time limit.

**Note:Take care to remove "$query->setFutureevents('true')", since futureevents will override startMin and startMax.**

Please find more http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html